# CSS multiple columns - paragraphs grouping?

Tags: css, multiple-columns

Is it possible use CSS column-count with grouped paragraphs?

I have

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>some paragraph of text 1</p>
<p>next paragraph of text 2</p>
<p>next paragraph of text 3</p>
```

With `p {column-count:2}` I get this:

```
 Heading
 some paragraph | of text 1
 next paragraph | of text 2
 next paragraph | of text 3
```

I need this:

```
 Heading
 some paragraph  | next paragraph
 of text 1       | of text 3
 next paragraph 
 of text 2
```

Is it possible?

https://codepen.io/kelv/pen/zVmePY - this is what I have.

https://i.ibb.co/B6rm66C/multiple-columns.png - this is what I need.

Comment: Can you add your html and css?

Comment: If you don’t want the content of each individual paragraph to be laid out in two columns, then _don’t_ apply the `column` property _to_ the individual paragraphs …

Comment: With columns you would get closer to your second example than your first - but to equalise the column height some of paragraph 2 may run into the second column

Comment: This might help but this is something close to what you want and not exactly the solution. https://codepen.io/townivan/post/flexbox-flex-direction-column

Comment: Or use css grid - https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-auto-flow/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout#Auto-placement_by_column

Comment: You need to introduce an additional container element to hold your paragraphs, and then apply `columns` to _that_. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qzJgGr

Comment: misorude: thanks, I know this solution, but realy is this not possible without container?

Answer (score 2):

First off: don't forget you close your paragraphs with `</p>`.

If I understand you correctly you need don't want that each separate paragraph has two columns, but you want to put the paragraphs in two columns. You need to put the `column-count` on a surrounding element:

```
<div class="paragraphs">
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</div>
```

---

```
.paragraphs {
   column-count:2
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydRwYy

Comment: Text is generated, I can not put in this own <div>.

Comment: Then I doubt it is possible, unless you can use JavaScript. Why can't you change the text generation?